# I can't connect via ssh to Google Compute Engine

Tags: ssh, debian, google-compute-engine

This is the second time this happens to me when I try to enter the instances of google compute engine is thinking and never connects. This is not how it happened before I had an instance and after time he did the same to me and I stopped connecting for Filezilla and for ssh.

Then I created a new one and after a year the truth happened again that I am in a situation where I cannot create another instance every time this happens.

Anyone know why it happens?

It is as if the connection is over and after 356 it is impossible to connect. My conclusion so far is that the sshKeys expires in the metadata because looking at the JSON at the end it says

```
{
  "userName": "info@poscloud.com.ar",
  "expireOn": "2019-12-05T20: 14: 23 +0000 "
}
```

I guess the problem comes from there, does anyone know how that is renewed?

I edit directly from there?

Another important fact that is strange what he does is that every time I have to connect with filezilla I have to create a new .ppk upload it to google and then it's like letting me connect about 3 4 times and then throws me "Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey) "and I have to recreate a new key.

The truth is that I am in a hurry with this subject because many clients depend on that instance and in this situation I cannot even connect.

Somebody could help me?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the SSH key is custom and before you upload a ssh key public SSH key to your project or instance metadata, you can edit metadata, format your keys to work with the Cloud Console or Gcloud command-line tool.

I would recommend either change the expiry date be a longer period of retention or remove the expiry date from the PKI. Please follow the attached document for reference.[[1]](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#sshkeyformat) [[2]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IMB_NyzBn7k) [[3]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z_ePcvnjQb4)

If the issue still persist, I would recommend to open your issue in Google issue tracker for further detailed [troubleshooting. [4]](https://issuetracker.google.com//issues/new?component=187134&template=1162877)